# Gauss-Krüger system to Unity cartesian Coordinate Conversion

Tags: coordinate-system, cartography, cartesian, unity3d

I have to deal with coordinate conversation into my unity (a game engine which uses cartesian co-ordinate) project but I am zero in this field as it is involved math, geometry, and geography with lots of jargon to understand. Here is my case:

I am getting OBJ (object file) which is on **Gauss-Kruger System**. I am also getting this kind of numbers data (maybe Gauss Kruger Coordinate) with the 3d object file.

```
"crs" : "M34",
"parameter" : "5720"

"datum" : "21000101"
```

Per object data:

```
"x0" : "10393.00",
    "y0" : "336847.00",
    "z0" : "134.84",
    "dx" : "128.00",
    "dy" : "128.00",
    "dz" : "2.49",
    "x0original" : "11033.00",
    "y0original" : "336847.00",
    "z0original" : "147.44"
```

I want to know that how exactly I place the model as I have several objects so coordinate conversion should work between UCS(unity coordinate system) and Gauss Kruger System. Previously I am able to convert my unity co-ordinate to Lat Long via [Unity GPS Conversion project](https://github.com/MichaelTaylor3D/UnityGPSConverter).